# When will functionality to Get MIME content of a message be available in v1.0 endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Currently we can get the mime content of the message from beta endpoint using the following request

```
GET /users/{id}/messages/{id}/$value
```

Is it possible to provide a timeline in when this feature will be available in v1.0 endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now shipped! Definitely keep an eye on our [Microsoft Graph blog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/mime-format-support-for-outlook-mail-and-attachments-translate-item-id-apis-are-now-available-in-microsoft-graph-v1-0/) and also our User Voice site for [feature requests](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/12253464-expose-the-entire-email-mime-stream-whole-mail-co) we are tracking status on.